# How to trigger function every http request in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, httprequest

I just wanna know if we can add a function in every http request?
ex.

```
$http.post('/Customer/FecthCustomer');
```

I mean all throughout the controller without putting the function each and every request there is.

I want to solve a problem where I cant get the page loaded event after the data from the server was fetch.
PS(window.setTimeout, window.load, $(document).ready,angular.element(document))
TESTED and DID NOT work, they only trigger every single load of the page.

Comment: Try searching with keyword "angularjs http interceptor".

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @holydragon!

Searched on [interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors).

Created this snippet:

```
angular.module('myModule', []).config(function($httpProvider) { 
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($rootScope) {
        return {
            'request': function (config) {
                console.log('REQUEST TRIGGERED');
                return config;
            }
        }
    });
})
```